# How can I check if a linked Component is first in the list?

Tags: dd4t, razormediator

I have the following syntax in a template using Razor Mediator:

```
<tcdl:ComponentField name="Fields.contact_nav">
    @foreach (dynamic link in Fields.contact_nav.links) {
        @if(link.IsFirst){...}
    }
</tcdl:ComponentField>
```

How do I write the `link.IsFirst` in MVC Razor? I have done the following:

```
@Html.SiteEditField(Model.Component,Model.Component.Fields["contact_nav"])
@foreach (var link in Model.Component.Fields["contact_nav"].LinkedComponentValues) {
    if(link.EmbeddedValues.First()){...}
}
```

But it is giving error for `EmbeddedValues`.

What am I doing wrong? How do I check whether a field is the first in a list or not in MVC Razor?

Comment: The main thing that you are doing wrong is asking MVC Razor question in the Tridion community instead of .NET/MVC specific community :)
I hope in communities like Stackoverflow you will get more responses which may help resolving your question quickly and effectively.
Please note, Razor mediator is a wrapper over MVC Razor and they may have different syntex

Comment: @PankajGaur I don't think this is an unreasonable question for this site. It is primarily programming related, yes, but it is heavily focused on the context of Tridion - just because it's on-topic elsewhere doesn't mean it's off-topic here.

Comment: Specifically, it's entirely reasonable to expect that this problem might be solved by some part of the DD4T API, which is explicitly on-topic as defined by "*programming related to Tridion and Tridion extensions*."

Comment: If community think so...I have no issues, however, as far as I know many such question which are in context with SDL Tridion but is related to some other technology or is related to programming have been closed in past.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To expand a little on what your problem is and why your solution won't work; the `IsFirst` property that you're using is part of the Razor Mediator's `DynamicItemFields` class and is explicitly set by the library, not a built-in part of any .NET collection type.

By contrast, when you use the [`Enumerable.First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb291976(v=vs.100).aspx) method as in your MVC example, you are not checking if the link is the first in the list, you are *querying* for the first embedded value in `link` that matches the provided expression (or in this case, as you pass no expression, the first embedded value in the `link` field), although since `link` is probably not an embeddable schema, there likely won't actually be any embedded values (not that it would help you if there were).

The most robust solution is probably just to set a flag:

```
@{
    bool first = true;
}
@foreach(var link in Model.Component.Fields["contact_nav"].LinkedComponentValues)
{
    if (first)
    {
        first = false;
        ...
    }
}
```

If you need more sophisticated index-related logic you would probably be better off using a standard `for` loop rather than a `foreach`.

```
@{
    var values = Model.Component.Fields["contact_nav"].LinkedComponentValues;
}

@for(int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
{
    if(i == 0)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```